# Angular routing add an extra slash to my url

Tags: angularjs, django, apache

I'm using `Angular` on `Django` with `Apache`. And I have an app like the following:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        // AngularJS modules define applications
        .module('app', ['ngRoute'])

        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl : "/static/app/foo/templates/main.html"
            })
            .when("/red", {
                templateUrl : "/static/app/foo/templates/red.html"
            });
        });

    function foo() { }
})();
```

I'm serving my site on: `http://localhost/ok/`

When I make a GET to `http://localhost/ok/` or to `http://localhost/ok`, all it's fine and the URL is transformed respectively to `http://localhost/ok/#!/` or to `http://localhost/ok#!/`.

In `main.html` I have a link to the `red` "anchor" `<a href="#red">Go to Red</a>`. It points to `http://localhost/ok/#red` but when I click it, `red.html` is not returned, and I read in the address bar `http://localhost/ok/#!/#red` or `http://localhost/ok#!/#red` (depending on the URL pattern of the first call).

I do not understand where the problem is. How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="#!/red">Go to Red</a>
```

Comment: Why that? It's very different from the common usages

Comment: It is common usage. Please see how links are constructed in official Angular tutorial: http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-9/app/#!/phones

Comment: Ok, I was following the w3c tutorial and urls were built like in my example. I'll take a look to your link!

Comment: It worked! I don't know why here http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp they use a different url pattern. (probably a different version of `angular-route.js`...)